# Open iOS Messages app and go directly to the Inbox/Messages list

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My goal is to view the messages in the SMS inbox.

I recognize that one cannot access the SMS inbox from within another application, so I have gone the route of:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

The problem with this, is that is pulls up the "New Message" screen.

Is there anyway I can avoid this and go directly to the list of messages?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there are only two URL schemes for Messages,

- "sms:" , that opens the "New message" screen
- "sms:1-408-555-1212" , that opens the "New message" screen with the number provided

As Apple developer documentation refers: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf

[Link updated]

Comment: Link appears to be dead.

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf